# Alter CSS Style for Elements Within a Link

Tags: html, css, parent-child, css-sprites, pseudo-element

Please bear with me as I try to explain what it is I am trying to do...

I have a grid of icons that will eventually become a custom-made service request page - each icon represents a different type of request a user can submit. Within these grids, we are trying to place a script-generated header text and the icon that represents/visualizes the request. This icon would also be a "sprite" which would change based on the status of the link its contained within (normal, hover, active, etc). To aid the users in effectively clicking the correct request type, the contents of each of the cells are to be within a link element for the given cell, meaning the user can click anywhere that cell exists to get to the next page - special formatting will be applied to delineate that area from the background.

The issue I am running into - and haven't been able to come up with a solution for - is how would I create this link for the entire cell AND be able to alter the CSS coding for the elements (in this case a H2 tag and a DIV) based on the state of the link (hover, active, etc), and what would the appropriate CSS coding look like?

I know you can do child/parent CSS codings, but is possible to do this for the pseudo-elements too? If so, how?

---

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" title="exampleCellLink" id="cellblock">
                <h2>Cell Block Title</h2>
                <div id="cellIcon">
                    <!-- DIV placeholder for the sprite image to be placed via CSS coding -->
                </div>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can include pseudo-elements in a CSS selector with any other selector types.  Can you provide an example (HTML) of what you're talking about?

Comment: @KatieK I've included an example of the HTML in question. Its obviously of one of the 12 cells, but all others will be formatted the same.

I need to be able to change the background image of the DIV within the link element via CSS to create the "Sprite" function, but can't seem to get it to work as I thought it would. The background of that DIV has to be controlled by the state of the link (hover, active, etc) but I don't know how to exactly do that with a child element within that link.

Answer (score 1):

You an do this very simply by applying a pseudo-selector to the parent element and include the children after it. Like this: `a:hover h2 { <properties on parent hover> } a:hover div { <properties on parent hover>}`

**Attention: In your code you used `<div id="cellicon">`. From the name, this sounds like a class. Just don't forget you break HTML if you re-use the same ID.**

You could also include all your icons in one sprite, for every link; suppose you have 5 icons (16x16px) with different properties for `:hover, :active and :visited` . Your sprite will have 4 images for each icon.

[image]

Code for every icon will be: (values from icon 2)

```css
a div { /* first specify the sprite for all links */
  background-image: url('...');
}
a#<linkid> div { /* normal state */
  background-position: -16px 0px;
}
a#<linkid>:hover div { /* hovered state */
  background-position: -16px -16px;
}
a#<linkid>:active div { /*active state */
  background-position: -16px -32px;
}
a#<linkid>:visited div { /* visited state */
  background-position: -16px -48px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for all that info! I was close in my guessing, but didnt know the pseudo-selector had to go before the child elements in question. I believe that takes care of it, but Ill know tomorrow when I finish up the code with your suggestions.